# What is a more Pythonic for-each-loop to use with Warning module?

Tags: python, foreach, warnings

I'm using the Python modules `fnmatch` and `warnings` for a pass/fail test with only a warning. If the tested event occurs, then just print a warning, but still continue execution.

```
haystack = ['*candy*','*apple*','*zebra*']
#haystack = ['*needle*','*apple*','*zebra*']
needle = "needle.txt"

aneedle = ''
i=5

while i:
    i-=1
    # START
    # FOR LOOP
    for hay in haystack:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(needle, hay):
            print("%s was found in %s." % (needle,hay))
            aneedle = hay
    # TEST
    if aneedle == '':
        warnings.warn("nothing found.")
    # END 
    print("Darn, %s" % (i,))
```

The not finding the needle raises a warning.

```
Darn, 4
Darn, 3
Darn, 2
Darn, 1
Darn, 0
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:18: UserWarning: nothing found.
```

This is a bit *tinker-toy* any suggestions for ...
***What is a more Pythonic pass/fail loop to use with Warning module?***

Comment: `try except finally` is the pythonic way https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: @RajanChauhan Opps. I needed the opposite--raise a warning if I don't find what I'm looking for. I fixed the code. But the point is if I get just one pass, then no warning. How does `try except finally` do that. It always runs `finally`?

Comment: Note. The code is the same, it's the variable names I changed to express the goal better. Finding 'marlboro' raised the warning before, where NOT finding 'needle' raises the warning now. Same structure, different names.

Comment: For pythonicity, try `import this`: simple is better than complex. You are trying to relate things that are unrelated, namely writing a pass/fail loop and issuing a warning. The pythonic way is to run the pass/fail loop separately, get the result (True or False, Exception raised or not), then issue a warning if you want. Write your code as if there was no warning to issue (it's a detail). Then, add the warning.

Comment: I thought the `aneedle=""` was a  bit hinkey. (>_<) but it works

Comment: A `None` value is often used to indicate lack of value. Initializing `aneedle = None` is perhaps a little more explicit. Then the test becomes `if aneedle is None`.